# Rendering rMarkdown File in a Markdown file

Tags: render, r-markdown, chunks

If I were to use `rmarkdown::render(myFile)` within an rMarkdown file. How would I get the first rMarkdown file to display the rendered second rMarkdown file? 
At present I've got:

`{r other, results="asis"}
myFile <- "SecondFile.Rmd"
rmarkdown::render(myFile)`

But this is just outputting the console text generated while the markdown is being knit, whereas obviously I want the HTML result of the knit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some fiddling the best answer I can come up with is this, but I'm more than happy for someone to correct me if there is a more 'proper' way.

````
```{r setup}
library(htmltools)
```
##Title

```{r generate, include=FALSE}
rmarkdown::render(myFile)
```

```{r print}
includeHTML(myFile)
```
````