# Include R script with markdown tags as external file in Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, knitr-spin

suppose I have an .R file `tmp.R` with markdown tags, e.g.

```
#' # header    
5+1
```

and I want to include that into a (much larger) `.Rmd` file as external source. R code and markdown tags shall be evaluated as if it were rendered directly. How I would do that?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```

I played around with several options, including

````
```{r, results='asis'}
source("tmp.R")
```
````

or

````
```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::spin("tmp.R')
```
````

and several others. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution on stackoverflow, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796501/is-it-possible-to-call-external-r-script-from-r-markdown-rmd-in-rstudio), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937931/how-to-include-external-r-file-with-rmarkdown), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547482/rendering-rmarkdown-file-in-a-markdown-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129020/render-r-script-in-tufte-output-with-r-markdown) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936990/markdown-and-outline-an-r-script) question.

Comment: what does your `tmp.R`-File look like? Your first option should work, depending on how you wrote the code in `tmp.R`

Comment: thank you for your swift response. the `tmp.R` file is the first code-junk. I wand the `.Rmd` file to interpret die markdown tag `#' # header`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if I understand your question, but it sounds to me that you were looking for `knitr::spin_child()`, which converts an R script to Rmd and knit it as a child document:

````
```{r}
knitr::spin_child('tmp.R')
```
````

Comment: Yes, I was. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the code in the `temp.R` file, in such a way, that it can directly be evaluated in the chunk.

So for tmp.R use:

```
cat("# header \n\n")
cat(4+3)
```

Then you can include this in the R-Markdown file with:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
source("tmp.R")
```
````

Comment: Oh, right. I actually stumbled across that one in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283042/r-markdown-output-test-results-in-loop). In this scenario I very much would like to not have to alter the R script. I understand that I would be able to implement a method that replaces the tags that follow the `#'` or `#'+` indicator accordingly. I wonder if there already is an out of the box solution for that